# INSERT,UPDATE in one Trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

Trigger to prevent update in one column, and another to check a value when insert, in the same Trigger,
I try my code bellow and it gives me error message when I try to insert into the Table !

Error : "Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted."

My Code :

```
create database twoTiggersTest
use twoTiggersTest

create table Commande(
ID int primary key,
DatCom date)

insert into Commande values(1,'01/16/2021')
insert into Commande values(2,'03/26/2021')

alter trigger prevent on Commande for update,insert
as
begin
   declare @DatCom date
   set @DatCom=(select DatCom from Commande where ID =(select ID from inserted)) 
   if(@DatCom < GETDATE() or update(ID))
      rollback
end
```

Comment: `set @DatCom=(select DatCom from Commande where ID =(select ID from inserted)` you do realize that `inserted` is a table that can hold more then one row, and thus will make this statement fail ?

Comment: @GuidoG but I'm inserting only one row !

Comment: there is no way to be certain of that, you or someone else might insert more rows in the future. A trigger is like everything in a database, it is `set based` Everything works with sets, not with single variables. Change your thinking in that direction and then I am sure you will figure out what you are doing wrong here

Comment: I tried also : set @DatCom=(select DatCom from inserted) same error

Comment: `set @DatCom=(select DatCom from inserted)` this has the exact same error as your first statement

Comment: And in answer, the way to do this is `throw`, not `rollback`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign to a single variable from a table, that is where you are wrong.
Try something like counting the number of rows in the `inserted` table that violate your rule, and then read the count and act on that

An example to get you started is this

```
alter trigger prevent on Commande for update,insert
as
begin
   set nocount on

   if exists (select 1 from inserted i where i.DateCom < GetDate())
     -- do your actions here
end
```

if you need to know if there are rows where the value for a column has changed, you can do it like this

```
   if exists ( select 1 
               from   inserted i 
                inner join deleted d on i.yourkeyfield = d.yourkeyfield
               where  (i.DatCom <> d.DatCom)
             )
     -- do your actions here
```

in case that DateCom can be null you need to add some more checks

Also note that it is not a good idea to rollback/commit inside a trigger, this must be handled by the caller.
Just `throw` an exception in your trigger and handle it in the caller

Comment: Urrgh you could just do an `if exists`. And you *can* assign a single variable, with `select`, but only get the last value

Comment: @Charlieface yes you could assign to a single variable if you pick the first or last using an order by, but I don't think that he needs that in this case. And yes, `if exists` is better

Comment: I need to check date in every insert, and prevent update ID in every update

Answer (score 0):

You will always get such an error if you rollback in a trigger.

The best way of doing this is to use `THROW`, instead of `ROLLBACK`, that way the client gets a proper error message:

```sql
create or alter trigger prevent on Commande for update,insert
as
begin
   if(update(DatCom) and exists(select 1
       from inserted i where i.DatCom < GETDATE() ))
      throw 50000, N'Wrong Date', 1;

   if(update(ID)
     and exists(select 1 from deleted)
     and exists(
       select i.ID from inserted i
       except
       select d.ID from deleted d ))
      throw 50001, N'Can''t Update ID', 1;
end
```

If you use the `UPDATE` function, this only tells you if the column was used in the update command, not whether the column actually changed. So you must always check the `inserted` and `deleted` tables for the difference. And it will always return true for inserts.

Comment: But here I have two conditions one for cheaking date if it's big than today, and the second one to prevent updating ID, if one of these conditions is false then rollback or throw

Comment: I need to check date in every insert, and prevent update ID in every update

Comment: I've given you the extra condition now

Comment: But I need to check date in Insert action not update

Comment: I tried your solution but doesn't allow me to insert values ! and it gives this error : Msg 3609, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Comment: You cannot get that error from only the code in this answer. There must be more code that you are not showing us.